# Setting up parameters

Tags: c

How would you create a function that prints binary from an integer, but with a certain amount of bits.

For example printBin ( 13 , 7)

would display

0001101

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

//Display integer number into binary using bitwise operator
void printBin(int num, int bits)
{
    int mask = 0x4000;
    if ((num & 0x8000) == 0)
       printf("0");
    else
       printf("1");

    while (mask != 0) 
    {
       if ((num & mask) == 0)
          printf("0");
       else
          printf("1");
       mask = mask >> 1;
    }
}

void main() 
{
    int intNum;
    int intBits;

    printf("\nEnter a integer number and number of bits :");
    scanf("%d %d", &intNum, &intBits);

    printf("\nInteger number in binary format :");
    printBin(intNum, intBits);

    getch();
}
```

Comment: need help solving how to create parameter

Comment: Please put in a little effort to format your code properly. In its current form, it is a pain to look at.

Answer (score 0):

You are massively over-complicating things. If I understand correctly what you want to do (I didn't read your code because the formatting is a mess), it is as simple as iterating through the bits you want to print, and printing each bit. Because you start with the highest index bit, run a for loop from largest index to 0.

Your function can be three lines:

```
void printBin(int num, int bits) {
    for (int i = bits-1; i >= 0; --i) {
        printf("%d",num>>i & 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: i need to input an interger, and a number of bits that the binary number should be, so if i put 13 and 7 in it should output 0001101

Comment: Yes, you said that. I think the function in my answer ought to work.

Answer (score 0):

- Try this one,

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  int main() 
  {
      int intNum = 13, intBin = 7;
       unsigned i;
       for (i = 1 << (intBin-1); i > 0; i = i / 2)
           (intNum & i)? printf("1"): printf("0");
      return 0;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <conio.h>

void printBin(int num, int bits){
    unsigned n = (unsigned)num;
    unsigned mask;
    int bit_len = sizeof(n) * CHAR_BIT;

    if(bits <= 0 || bits > bit_len)
        return ;

    for(mask = 0x1 << --bits; mask; mask >>= 1){
        putchar(n & mask ? '1' : '0');
    }
}

int main(void){
    int intNum, intBits;

    printf("\nEnter a integer number and number of bits :");
    scanf("%d %d", &intNum, &intBits);

    printf("\nInteger number in binary format :");
    printBin(intNum, intBits);puts("");

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you explain what is going on in funcion line by line